# URL extraction from multiple webpages

Tags: powershell, security

I wanted to extract URLs from multiple domains and save the unique output values into one txt file. The URLs have different format, some have http, https, 127.0.0.1. I only wanted to get the URLs and remove the prefixes, specially '127.0.0.1' I tried the following ps script but it doesn't give me any result. Any help please to fix this issue.

```
`$threatFeedUrls =@("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DandelionSprout/adfilt/master/Alternate%20versions%20Anti-Malware%20List/AntiMalwareHosts.txt",
                     "https://osint.digitalside.it/Threat- 
Intel/lists/latestdomains.txt")

#Initialize an array to store all extracted URLs
$allUrls = @()

#Loop through the lists of URLs
foreach ($url in $threatFeedUrls) {

# Download the threat feed data
$threatFeedData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $threatFeedUrl

# Define a regular expression pattern to match URLs starting with '127.0.0.1'
$pattern = '127\.0\.0\.1 ([^\s]+)'

# Use the regular expression to find matches in the threat feed data
$matchList = [regex]::Matches($threatFeedData, $pattern)

# Create and populate the list with matched URLs
$urlList = 
foreach ($match in $matchList) {
   $match.Groups[1].Value
      }

# Specify the output file path
$outputFilePath = 'output250.txt'
  
# Save the URLs to the output file
$urlList | Out-File -FilePath $outputFilePath

Write-Host "URLs starting with '127.0.0.1' extracted from threat feed have been saved to        $outputFilePath."
}`
```

i wrote PS script to extract all the URLs. But the out put is not what i expected. I wanted to get an extraction of all URLs from the domains listed, remove the duplicates and save them in one txt file

Comment: You create a loop variable `$url` but you are using `$threatFeedUrl` inside the loop wich is not defined. ☝ ... and `$allUrls` is defined but never used. ... but that's actually just cosmetic. 

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
# Define the URLs to get
$threatFeedUrls = @(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DandelionSprout/adfilt/master/Alternate%20versions%20Anti-Malware%20List/AntiMalwareHosts.txt",
    "https://osint.digitalside.it/Threat-Intel/lists/latestdomains.txt"
)
# Get all the raw files
$Result = $threatFeedUrls | foreach {Irm -Uri $_ -UseBasicParsing} 

# Filter out comments and empty lines
$OnlyInterestingLines = $Result -split "`n" | where {$_ -notmatch "^(#|\s|$)" }

# Remove 127.0.0.1 at the beginning of lines followed by any amount of whitespace, remove anything on the left side of a ":" and remove up to two "/" when it matches, sort it and return only unique addresses
$urlList = $OnlyInterestingLines -replace "^127\.0\.0\.1\s*" -replace "^.*:/?/?" | Sort-Object -Unique

# Specify the output file path
$outputFilePath = 'output250.txt'

# Save the URLs to the output file
$urlList | Out-File -FilePath $outputFilePath
```

Result are 21.780 lines of hostnames

Edit: maybe you would like to remove any kind of protocol, too. So now i remove them as well. It would remove protocols in cases like thes `https:youaddress.com` `http:youaddress.com` `https://youaddress.com` `http:youaddress.com` `ftp:youaddress.com` `socks:youaddress.com` `yourtest:/youaddress.com` any many more. all of these examples would return `youaddress.com`

Comment: Thank you An-dir. The script only extracted URLs that have '127.0.0.1'. There are URLs with different format, such as with http, https, or no prefix at all like (abcd.ef). Not sure how to include all kinds of URL formats in one script. Any clue please

Comment: my script extracted all addresses you had in your two example lists. Excluded are addresses that are part of a comment. the 127.0.0.1 are most addresses because the other list is short. what do you need? "https://" and other protocols, simply removed? any examples please. your examples don't have https:// - or do you need the protocols added ?

Comment: Just made a change you might need

Comment: forexample, this domain (https://firebog.net/) contains URLs with https lists.

Comment: So I assume you take the txt lists from https://v.firebog.net/hosts/static/w3kbl.txt list and place them in `$threatFeedUrls` so that their content can get parsed. So it should work for your needs.